# Different rewrite rules custom post type and taxonomy - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I created two rewrite rules for Wordpress. One for my custom post type and one for a taxonomy.
See code below

```
//Add permalink structure posts
add_filter('post_type_link', function($link, $post = 0){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    if($wp_rewrite->permalink_structure !== ''){
        if($post->post_type == 'catalog'){
            $clean_url = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", " ", get_the_title($post->ID))));
            return home_url('/' . $clean_url . '/' . $post->ID);
        }else{
            return $link;
        }
    }else{
        return $link;
    }
}, 1, 3);   

//Add permalink structure taxonomy terms
add_filter( 'term_link', function($link, $term, $taxonomy){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    if($wp_rewrite->permalink_structure !== ''){
        if ( 'parts' === $taxonomy ) {
            $clean_url = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", " ", $term->slug)));
            return home_url('/' . $clean_url . '/' . $term->term_id);
        }
    }else{
        return $link;
    }
}, 10, 3 );

//Add rewrite rule cpt catalog
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$',
    'index.php?post_type=catalog&p=$matches[2]',
    'top'
); 

//Add rewrite rule taxonomy parts
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$',
    'index.php?parts=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

Now I get an error 404 for the catalog post because the rewrite rule for taxonomy is active. This happens because I coded the taxonomy rewrite rule after the post rewrite rule.

So my question is how can I create multiple rewrite rules for different post types and taxonomies?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is related with the regexp parameters that you used.

You can write multiple `add_rewrite_rule($regex, $query, $after)` methods. But if you give same or comprehensive regexps for different rules, they overlap each other and the latest one works.

For your code:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$',
    'index.php?post_type=catalog&p=$matches[2]',
    'top'
); 

add_rewrite_rule(
    '^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$',
    'index.php?parts=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

You should edit regexps (first parameters of these functions) to match your catalog and taxonomy page URLs. If I understand your permalink structure correctly, I think it is not possible since you have test.com/123456 for both catalog and taxonomy pages. Maybe you can check the id length or something else to separate and find different exact matches for each.

If you okay with changing the permalink structure you can basically add a prefix to catalog like

```
return home_url('/cat/' . $clean_url . '/' . $post->ID);
```

or same for taxonomies.